# Divisor function of factorials and other integers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Is there a proof or any known value of $x$, for which  $x<n!$ and  $\sigma(n!)<\sigma(x)$

Answer (score 0):

For $n=9$, we have $\sigma(9!) = 1481040$ and $\sigma(360360) = 1572480$, where $360360 < 362880 = 9!$.

Comment: wow thanks! that was too easy!